# Should unit test follow PSR?

Tags: php, testing, phpunit

We use PSR1 in our project.

After a discussion regarding unit tests we decided to use the method 2 of these:
https://dzone.com/articles/7-popular-unit-test-naming

However someone pointed out that it does not follow PSR.

Is this a valid argument? Should unit test follow PSR?

Comment: Oh well. I see people downvoting and voting to close this as opinion based. Maybe someone cares to explain why? Good practices are opinion based after all, "as long a the code executes".

Comment: Your question is a bit broad. `someone pointed out` is pretty vague. Be more specific!

Answer (score 2):

Following a PSR is not obligatory, it's your choice. There are good reasons to follow such a standard, but there might be good reasons to not follow them.

I think it depends on how the code is used. For a widely spread library or framework I would recommend following a PSR standard because others can read the code more easily.

If the project is just for your developer team (closed source), your team should decide which standards to follow. Only your team needs to work with the code then and IMHO the best coding standard is the one that enables the developers to work as smooth as possible with the code.

Comment: A team is not a closed system. People enter and leave the team. Following an open standard is not the worst idea.